# Нужно ли обособление запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Создание иностранной консульской сети(,) во многом в помощь паломникам-мусульманам(,) является свидетельством того...**
Нужно ли обособление (запятые в скобках)?

Comment: Если признать такое предложение корректным, то обособление нужно. Но у меня нет уверенности в том, что так можно выражаться.

Comment: Выражаются. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Уважаемый М_Г! Если Вы добавите ОТВЕТ, то я смогу отметить его полезность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создание иностранной консульской сети, **во многом  для помощи паломникам-мусульманам,**  является свидетельством того...

Оборот обособляется **по двум причинам:**

1) содержит дополнительную информацию; 2) не вписывается в структуру основного предложения, чему препятствует наречие "во многом".

Сравнить: Создание иностранной консульской сети для помощи паломникам-мусульманам является свидетельством того...

Comment: Jasmin, Вы без комментариев заменили *в* на *для*. Именно предлог *в* меня смущал в данном  предложении. Так что комментарии  будут приняты с благодарностью.

Comment: Прежде всего  для благозвучия (встреча двух похожих предлогов).  Предлог В  и В.п. обозначает направленность, а предлог ДЛЯ и Р.п. - предназначенность, по семантике они здесь взаимозаменяемы, хотя  излишнюю направленность тоже желательно исключить.  А теперь мне еще кажется, что "в помощь" в данном случае имеет разговорный оттенок.

Answer (score 2):

**Создание иностранной консульской сети, во многом в помощь паломникам-мусульманам, является свидетельством того...**

Наречие [**во многом**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/323162/%D0%B2%D0%BE) в этом контексте имеет такой смысл:
*большей частью, **по большей части*** (а также — *в основном, преимущественно, в первую очередь, в большей степени, в значительной мере).*

*Во многом* обычно не требует обособления. Однако, если слова *во многом* начинают собой присоединительный оборот, **содержащий дополнительные замечания или разъяснения,** то они обособляются вместе со всем оборотом.

**[По большей части](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_891)** (= во многом)

Answer (score 1):

Если признать такое предложение корректным, то обособление нужно. Но у меня нет уверенности в том, что так можно выражаться.

Comment: Согласен, что криво, но цель была исправить ошибки. Переписывать тексты за авторов совсем "не в кассу".